# What is better Mounting S3 bucket or copying files from S3 bucket to windows EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a use case where the CSV files are stored on an S3 bucket by a service. My program running on windows EC2 has to use the CSV files dumped on S3 bucket. Mounting or copying, which approach will be better to use the file? And how to approach it.

Answer (score 1):

Mounting the bucket as a local Windows drive will just cache info about the bucket and copy the files locally when you try to access them. Either way you will end up having the files copied to the Windows machine. If you don't want to program the knowledge of the S3 bucket into your application then the mounting system can be an attractive solution, but in my experience it can be very buggy. I built a system on Windows machines in the past that used an S3 bucket mounting product, but after so many bugs and failures I ended up rewriting it to simply perform an `aws s3 sync` operation to a local folder before the process ran.

Answer (score 1):

I always suggest copying using either by CLI or directly using endpoints or SDK or whatever the way suggested by AWS but not mounting.

Actually, S3 is not built for a filesystem purpose. It's an object storage system. NOt saying that you cannot do it, but it is not advisable. The correct way to use Amazon S3 is to put/get files using the S3 APIs.

And if you are concerned about the network latency, I would say both will be the same and if you are thinking about directly modifying/editing a file within the file system, No you cannot Since Amazon S3 is designed for atomic operations, they have to be completely replaced with modified files.